# How to build an image with Dockerfile in Kitematic?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, kitematic

Is there anyway to build an image with Dockerfile while using Kitematic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [top of the docs](https://docs.docker.com/kitematic/userguide/) for Kitematic

> Legacy desktop solution. Kitematic is a legacy solution, bundled with Docker Toolbox. We recommend updating to Docker for Mac or Docker for Windows if your system meets the requirements for one of those applications.

If possible, you should avoid using the tool.

---

If you have to use Kitematic, the feature you are asking about is tracked by this GitHub issue: [Import Dockerfile - (Docker build)](https://github.com/docker/kitematic/issues/574). *At the time of writing the feature is not implemented.*